# What's the best way to provide quality answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

I'm looking for some advice on providing good quality answers without reinventing the wheel every time. I have noticed a lot of solutions require the question author read *and* understand documentation or codex. Obviously linking to the documentation does not make it any clearer and most people don't click those links anyway. What's the best way to go about this?

I know "RTFM!" isn't the right answer, but rewriting the codex isn't the answer, either.

I have read [Help Center > Answering](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). I think this question is an extension of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes answers require repeating information already written down in The Codex/Handbook. I find the best solution is rephrasing what's already been said or providing an example that fits what the original poster is asking for. Maybe The Codex doesn't quite frame ideas in a way the original poster understands which is where you could try and simplify these ideas and examples.

If I were to define what a good answer is, I would say that **good answers are descriptive**.

Here's an example that's literally [creating a custom post type and taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/185591/7355). Sure it's a topic that's been pretty extensively described online but I still tried to break it down into a few simple steps. At least 12 people found it helpful in one way or another.

There's never enough examples. Feel free to repeat, rephrase, redescribe something that you may find easy ( or easily discoverable ) to help someone out.